# Pass position to Onclick

Tags: android

I'm using a list and I want to display a different AlertDialog for every list item, and a different message when "yes" or "no" button is clicked in this AlertDialog.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id ){
            dialogBox.setMessage(dialogBoxMessage[position]);
            dialogBox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext() , resultOfNoClick[position] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }

            });
        }
    } );
```

The "resultOfNoClick" is an array of Strings, which contains every String that needs to be shown for a "No" click in a specific item on the ListView. So, There is a way to pass the position (the variable received by "onItemClick") as a parameter to the "onClick" function above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a **final** variable:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id ){
                dialogBox.setMessage(dialogBoxMessage[position]);
                dialogBox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext() , resultOfNoClick[position] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }

                });
            }
        } );
```